# Django blog APPS

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Are there  any plug and play blog APPS for django,if so please point me to the sources for it.

I am actually looking something like word press which is of cousre difficult to integrate with django.

Thanks..

Comment: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/29/django-blog/

Comment: Google and Django Packages give you tons of choices: http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We looked into this a few months ago for our site and found that [Mezzanine](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine) and [Zinnia](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia) were the two best options available, and both are regularly-maintained.

Mezzanine gives you a slicker interface than Zinnia and has disqus comment integration, and has recently added Akismet integration for spam filtering on comments.

Comment: Worth noting Mezzanine isn't an app, it's a full project/Django based framework. If you are looking to add blogging functionality to an existing Django project I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

[django-blog-it](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/django-blog-it) - complete customization and ready to use with one click installer. You can try it by hosting on your own or deploy to Heroku with a button click.

Features:

- Dynamic blog articles
- Blog pages
- Contact us page (configurable)
- google analytics
- List item
- SEO compliant

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm not sure but I think you might look at [this one](http://blogmaker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/release/README.html).
Also [project Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) contains blog.